# onChange function, summing values

Tags: javascript

Basically I am trying to calculate an input field value * a hidden field value (this is working). I am doing this in 2 fields, both are working. Then I am trying to add their values together, this is where I am stuck.....see code. I would greatly appreciate any help, thank you in  advance.

```js
function updatesum() {
  document.form.sum.value = (document.form.sum1.value - 0) * (document.form.sum2.value - 0);
}

function updatesum2() {
  document.form.sum5.value = (document.form.sum3.value - 0) * (document.form.sum4.value - 0);
}

function updatesum3() {
  document.form.sum6.value = (document.form.sum.value - 0) + (document.form.sum5.value - 0);
}
```

```html
  <form name="form">
    Number of adults:
    <input name="sum1" onChange="updatesum()" />

    <input name="sum2" type="hidden" value="15" onChange="updatesum()" />Total:
    <input name="sum" readonly style="border:0px;">Number of adults:
    <input name="sum3" onChange="updatesum2()" />

    <input name="sum4" type="hidden" value="15" onChange="updatesum2()" />Total:
    <input name="sum5" readonly style="border:0px;">Total2:
    <input name="sum6" readonly style="border:0px;">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You never called your updatesum3() function. You have onChange events for your updatesum() and updatesum2() functions. You can call the updatesum3() function from both the updatesum() and updatesum2() functions.

```
function updatesum() {
   document.form.sum.value = (document.form.sum1.value -0) * (document.form.sum2.value -0);
   updatesum3();
}

function updatesum2() {
   document.form.sum5.value = (document.form.sum3.value -0) * (document.form.sum4.value -0);
   updatesum3();
}
```

Comment: Im still learning, thank you so much, your a beautiful person!